# How to run dohell command with hackbench?

Tags: linux, real-time

I am missing a point w.r.t the usage of **dohell** command. Please point out.

```
anisha@linux-dopx:~/Desktop/RealTime/downloadedPages> /usr/xenomai/bin/dohell -b ~/Desktop/RealTime/downloadedPages/hackbench
/usr/xenomai/bin/dohell [ -b path ] [ -s server ] [ -p port ] [ -m mntpoint ] [ -l path | seconds ]

Generate load, using an assorted set of commands and optionnaly:
[B]- hackbench if the path to the hackbench binary is specified with -b;[/B]
- nc to send TCP data to "server" port "port" if -s is specified (if -p
is not specified, the port 9, aka discard is used);
- dd to write data under "mntpoint" if -m is specified.

during the runtime of the LTP test if the path to the LTP installation
directory is specifed with -l or during "seconds" seconds.
```

What's in the directory:

```
anisha@linux-dopx:~/Desktop/RealTime/downloadedPages> ls
adeosPaper.pdf                                      How To Do Eveything With DD - LinuxQuestions.org_files
AnatomyOfRealTimeLinux.pdf                          How To Do Eveything With DD - LinuxQuestions.org.html
BasicsOfRealTimeLinux.html                          LifeWithAdeos.pdf
dd (Unix) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia_files  Makefile
dd (Unix) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia.html   mythsAndFactsRT.pdf
FAQsXenomai.html                                    NativeAPITour.pdf
[B][COLOR="red"]hackbench[/COLOR][/B]                                           resourceKernel
hackbench.c                                         RTAI_User_Manual_34_03 (1).pdf
history.pdf                                         xeno-test
```

Type of hackbench:

```
anisha@linux-dopx:~/Desktop/RealTime/downloadedPages> file hackbench
hackbench: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, not stripped
```

---

I tried `dohell` separately with `hackbench` and `seconds` parameter
as follows (and it worked properly):

```
linux-dopx:~ # /usr/xenomai/bin/dohell -b
"/home/anisha/Desktop/RealTime/downloadedPages/hackbench -pipe 100
process 100 seconds" 2
Running with 100*40 (== 4000) tasks.
Time: 2.198
/usr/xenomai/bin/dohell: line 94: 17276 Terminated              while :; do
   $hackbench 1;
done
/usr/xenomai/bin/dohell: line 94: 17277 Terminated              while :; do
   cat /proc/interrupts;
done > /dev/null 2>&1
/usr/xenomai/bin/dohell: line 94: 17279 Terminated              while :; do
   ps w;
done > /dev/null 2>&1
/usr/xenomai/bin/dohell: line 94: 17280 Terminated              dd
if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null
/usr/xenomai/bin/dohell: line 94: 17281 Terminated              while :; do
   ls -lR / > /dev/null 2>&1;
done
Killed
```

Then I tried the same with `xeno-test` as follows:

```
/usr/xenomai/bin/xeno-test -l "dohell -b
"/home/anisha/Desktop/RealTime/downloadedPages/hackbench -pipe 100
process 100 seconds" 2"
and
/usr/xenomai/bin/xeno-test -l "dohell -b
/home/anisha/Desktop/RealTime/downloadedPages/hackbench -pipe 100
process 100 seconds 2"
and
/usr/xenomai/bin/xeno-test -l dohell -b
/home/anisha/Desktop/RealTime/downloadedPages/hackbench -pipe 100
process 100 seconds 2
and also,
/usr/xenomai/bin/xeno-test -l "dohell -b
/home/anisha/Desktop/RealTime/downloadedPages/hackbench -pipe 100
process 100" -T 2
and
/usr/xenomai/bin/xeno-test -l "dohell -b
/home/anisha/Desktop/RealTime/downloadedPages/hackbench -pipe 100
process 100" -t 2
```

All of them resulted in the same end results:
**What is the way to run this?** Please help.

Comment: I ran the same in some other different ways (edit in the question), but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course specifying the time duration is a must, but

```
xeno-test -l "dohell -b /home/anisha/Desktop/RealTime/downloadedPages/hackbench -pipe 100  process 100 14400"
```

still doesn't give desired outputs.
The problem is in the "parameters" specified with hackbench.
The sub `dohell` command (with hackbench parameters) works well (individually), but it doesn't work when attached with `xeno-test`.

I removed the hackbench's parameters (`"-pipe 100 process 100"`), then it started working with `xeno-test`.

The following works:
`xeno-test -l "dohell -b /home/anisha/Desktop/RealTime/downloadedPages/hackbench 14400"`

https://mail.gna.org/public/xenomai-help/2012-04/msg00073.html
https://mail.gna.org/public/xenomai-help/2012-04/msg00074.html

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter is mandatory.

Either pass a path to your LTP installation if you have one using the `-l` switch, or a number of seconds to run.

(`dohell` is a [plain shell script](http://repo.or.cz/w/xenomai-head.git/blob/fa861ba04e6dc5a8e66fdd7a03c3d8c942097858:/src/testsuite/xeno-test/dohell), you could just look at it to check how it works.)

Comment: thanks, I'll try it out. But the above output doesn't mention that the last parameter is compulsory, does it?

Comment: I have edited the question - please see. It isn't yet solved.